# Correlation for priors in BLRM with EWOC in R package OncoBayes2

Tags: r, bayesian, correlation, prior

I'm trying to reproduce results in [this](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ProvidedDocs/64/NCT02108964/Prot_001.pdf) protocol with [OncoBayes2 package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OncoBayes2/OncoBayes2.pdf) to learn [BLRM with EWOC](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sim.3230) (Neuenschwander 2008) in dose finding studies. In section 14.2.2.1 (appendix 2) of the protocol it gives the prior median, sd and correlation of log alpha and log beta as mean: -3.068,0.564 sd: 2.706,0.728 corr: -0.817. The documentation of OncoBayes2 package seems to use diagonal matrix for the prior sd and therefore the correlation is not considered into the priors.

I tried the following code, with no correlation specified:

```
library(tibble)


EGF816_prior = blrm_trial(data = tibble(group_id = as.factor("All"), 
                                    drug_A = NA, 
                                    num_patients = NA, 
                                    num_toxicities = NA), 
                      dose_info = tibble(group_id = as.factor("All"), 
                                         drug_A = c(50,75,150,300,450,600,800,1000), 
                                         dose_id = seq(1, 8, 1), stratum_id = "all"), 
                      drug_info = tibble(drug_name = "drug_A", 
                                         dose_ref = 300, 
                                         dose_unit = "mg/kg"), 
                      simplified_prior = FALSE, 
                      EXNEX_inter = FALSE, 
                      EX_prob_inter = 1, 
                      interval_prob = c(0, 0.16, 0.33, 1), 
                      interval_max_mass = c(prob_underdose = 1, 
                                            prob_target = 1, 
                                            prob_overdose = 0.25), 
                      prior_EX_mu_mean_comp = matrix(c(-3.068,0.564), 1, 2, TRUE), 
                      prior_EX_mu_sd_comp = matrix(c(2.706,0.728),1, 2), 
                      prior_EX_tau_mean_comp = matrix(c(0, 0), 1, 2), 
                      prior_EX_tau_sd_comp = matrix(c(1, 1), 1, 2), 
                      prior_EX_prob_comp = matrix(1, nrow = 1, ncol = 1), 
                      prior_tau_dist = 0,
                      prior_PD = FALSE)

summary(EGF816_prior,"dose_prediction")
```

It gives:

```
group_id drug_A dose_id stratum_id   mean    sd       `2.5%`   `50%` `97.5%`  prob_underdose  prob_target  prob_overdose ewoc_ok

1 All          50       1 all        0.0387 0.118 0.0000000278 0.00134   0.423          0.932      0.0348        0.0332 TRUE   
2 All          75       2 all        0.0515 0.136 0.000000419  0.00281   0.514          0.905      0.0488        0.0462 TRUE   
3 All         150       3 all        0.0894 0.182 0.0000208    0.0104    0.721          0.839      0.07          0.0912 TRUE   
4 All         300       4 all        0.173  0.252 0.000236     0.0468    0.899          0.692      0.112         0.196  TRUE   
5 All         450       5 all        0.260  0.308 0.000527     0.109     0.970          0.573      0.124         0.303  FALSE  
6 All         600       6 all        0.328  0.340 0.000811     0.178     0.990          0.481      0.136         0.383  FALSE  
7 All         800       7 all        0.396  0.361 0.00118      0.278     0.998          0.404      0.130         0.466  FALSE  
8 All        1000       8 all        0.447  0.372 0.00160      0.377     0.999          0.355      0.120         0.526  FALSE
```

The result is similar to the prior distribution listed in table 14-7 in the protocol. Considering that the package uses MCMC for calculation so it is acceptable to not have the exact same numbers, can I assume that the correlation between log alpha and log beta is not actually affecting the results? Moreover, where should I put the correlation in the code if I want to specify it?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you'are right (By yes I mean the package does not take into account correlation when sampleing). And yes correlation will affect the results and that's why you can't reproduce table 14-7 closely enough.

By checking the source code of OncoBayes2 one can confirm that the sampling provided in the package does NOT take into account the correlation between alpha0 and alpha1. That's why you'll find the result from dose 300 will be the most closest to that in Table 14-7 in the protocol -- because that's the reference, so only alpha0 will affect the results, hence no correlation provided will not affect the results. But other rows will always be some off from that in Table 14-7.

I'm also trying to replicate the results in Table 14-7. My solution is to modify the source stan code to add that support of correlation, then the results will be very close.

So I'm thinking what Novartis releases is not what they used internally, at least with some functionality missing.

If you want, you can checkout my [modified version of Oncobayes2](https://github.com/fenguoerbian/MyOncoBayes2). This adds the support of user specified correlation.